# Computing session from users' action logs

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, analytics

We have a mobile application which generates logs from users' actions. I copied sample logs below, I want to find the average time that a single user worked with the application, as you can see I have userIds and the exact time that an action has been occurred, the problem is I can not find the user usage time (session). I am sure there is a algorithm that solves my problem. I know that some tools like google-analytics does the same but I want to know the exact value of user active time in each session, average active time and average session time; per user and for all users.

```
ID   UserID Action  ActionID    CreatedDateTime   
6452477 54261   37  30889   2016-03-28 08:41:43.110
6452476 54261   37  30889   2016-03-28 08:41:42.590
6452475 54261   37  30889   2016-03-28 08:41:42.590
6452474 54261   45  30889   2016-03-28 08:41:42.030
6452473 54261   45  30889   2016-03-28 08:41:42.030
6452472 40906   81  20      2016-03-28 08:41:32.853
6452471 40906   22  210718  2016-03-28 08:41:32.003
6452470 22812   15  58598   2016-03-28 08:41:29.913
6452469 54261   81  0       2016-03-28 08:41:29.717
6452468 54261   81  0       2016-03-28 08:41:29.700
6452467 22812   15  58598   2016-03-28 08:41:22.233
6452466 22812   15  58598   2016-03-28 08:41:22.040
6452465 22812   25  58598   2016-03-28 08:41:22.020
6452464 22812   15  58598   2016-03-28 08:41:22.017
6452463 40906   81  10      2016-03-28 08:41:02.023
6452462 38296   32  31237   2016-03-28 08:41:01.970
6452461 455     32  29596   2016-03-28 08:41:01.967
6452460 38258   22  210717  2016-03-28 08:40:58.930
6452459 22812   412 -1      2016-03-28 08:40:56.860
6452458 22812   82  0       2016-03-28 08:40:52.820
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, as I know, there are some functions which get executed when some special events occurred. For example, `onResume()`, `onDestroy()`, `onPause()` and `onCreate()`. These are for Android and I know that there are some for iOS and other platforms.
When you want to get the session time for a user, I think it is possible to calculate the time between `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` as well as `onResume()` and `onPause()`, so you will be able to get the exact time of a user's session in a single activity.

Comment: I think he wanna know how to calculate the session from the above log...not with the native mobile functions...!

Comment: It's ok, he can log those functions! If he didn't know when onPause and onDestroy have been occurred, how he would be able to get exact time? I think it's impossible.

Comment: @jmosawy I have no access to my mobile application on client like this. I have my users' actions' logs. I want to compute data from the logs I have on my server side.

Comment: @RezaAmeri What do you mean by `having no access?` I think there is something behind your `Action` and `ActionID` columns and I guess they are meant to be pointed to special events on your client application, so if you are logging those events I have mentioned above, then you may be lucky to get users time that they are spending in your application, otherwise, IMO it is somehow impossible or imprecise. In the meantime, why you do not just update your application to start logging those events, if you are not till now? They are parts of most important events that occur in a client application.